# How can I mount a Rackspace Cloud Files as a drive on a Mac & PC?

Tags: cloud-storage

I want to have seamless access to my Rackspace files on my laptops.

How do I mount my Rackspace as a drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudberry has a product with a free demo.

http://www.cloudberrylab.com/virtual-drive-amazon-s3-azure.aspx

> **Map Cloud Storage as a Network Drive**
>
> CloudBerry Drive beta maps your cloud storage as a local disk to access and edit files in the cloud directly from the Windows Explorer interface.
>
> CloudBerry Drive comes with an easy installation and configuration that seamlessly integrates cloud storage as a virtual disk with the Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

I use [**cloudfuse**](https://github.com/redbo/cloudfuse) to do that on Linux, and I use [**bonkey**](https://sites.google.com/site/thebackupmonkey/) for backing up to Cloud Files on Windows, which also runs on Macs.  It's not quite what you asked for, but I thought they may be useful to you, and others who read this.

You can also acess Rackspace Cloud Files using any file transfer tool with `HTTPS` support, like [**cURL**](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [**Cyberduck**](http://cyberduck.ch/).

There is also [**Interarchy**](http://nolobe.com/interarchy/), for the Mac, but I have no experience with that.

---

**Additionally:**
Since I originally answered this I have been using [**SMEStorage Cloud**](http://smestorage.com/), which is quite amazing.  It allows you to connect to many different storage providers and your own servers through different methods, and move files between them.  There are browser extensions and you get two free providers, which you can choose, and some free Amazon S3 storage space.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this tool: http://www.gladinet.com/p/moreAboutdesktop.htm which works.

Caveat: I haven't purchased this yet, but I installed the demo and it worked as advertised.

Comment: Looks great, but it's not Mac-ready.

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace owns [JungleDisk](https://www.jungledisk.com/personal/desktop/features/) which mounts a bucket as a local drive; you can mount multiple buckets as multiple drives, IIRC.  Versions for Windows/Mac/Linux.  Compatible with Rackspace Cloud files and Amazon S3.

Costs USD 3/month on top of storage fees.

Comment: I'm not sure you can hook Jungledisk up to existing Cloud Files instances. The last time I looked, Jungledisk created specially named CF containers.

Comment: @hyperslug: `Jungle Disk` is not integrated with `Rackspace Cloud Files`.  `Rackspace Cloud Drive` is the same thing as `Jungle Disk`, but with different branding.  Neither `Jungle Disk` or `Rackspace Cloud Drive` are available outside the US any more, and `Rackspace Cloud Files` seems to be replacing them both gradually.